# Synchronize Facebook comments to Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, comments

I don't seem to find an answer for this one that I'm able to understand. I read in various places that comments made through the FB comments plugin on a website can also be synchronized with a Facebook Page. So far I haven't found out how this is supposed to work.